# How do I use a js dependency after I do NPM install?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, fuse.js

How do I use a dependency in my javascript after I install it using npm? I just used NPM to install [Fuse.js](http://fusejs.io). `npm install fuse.js`

Then the website says to use the program I just have to add the following code and it will work:

```
var books = [{
  'ISBN': 'A',
  'title': "Old Man's War",
  'author': 'John Scalzi'
}, {
  'ISBN': 'B',
  'title': 'The Lock Artist',
  'author': 'Steve Hamilton'
}]

var options = {
  keys: ['title', 'author'],
  id: 'ISBN'
}
var fuse = new Fuse(books, options)

fuse.search('old')
```

But I keep getting console error `Fuse is not defined.` for the code `var fuse = new Fuse(books, options)` How do I get fuse defined after I do npm install?

I tried this [site](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-locally) from node, and added `require('Fuse')` but that did not help. I continued to get the same error.

Comment: `var Fuse=require('Fuse')`  is it similar to this exactly??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import the `Fuse` class before you can use it.

I think you can do that using something like this:

```
import Fuse from "fuse.js"
```

Comment: I tried that now I am getting an error `__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_fuse_js__.Fuse is not a constructor`

Comment: @Whitecat Try: `import Fuse = require('fuse.js')`

Comment: That is for type script. This is what did the trick `import Fuse from 'fuse.js'`

Comment: @Whitecat I guess `Fuse` is the **default export**.

Comment: Thank you for helping debug that issue.

Answer (score 3):

Node.js provide isolation of modules. If you want to use any package/dependency then you need to import it. Node.js follow commonJS module pattern so you need to add following line before using `var fuse = new Fuse(books, options)`

```
var Fuse = require('fuse.js')
```

It's a good practice to add this line on top of your file.

Comment: If I do this I get the error `'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'; throw e;` `"Cannot find module \"Fuse\""`

Comment: That works for type script not JS which I am working in.